# Why does my pygame.group have a null value when it's in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently programming a pygame version of othello. I have tried to implement a function "flip_piece" which flips a single piece from white to black and vice versa. However, it involves finding the piece to flip, and in doing so I have to loop through my piece list, which then returns a null value despite my having filled it.

Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)


class Piece(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


def set_up_pieces(piece_list):
    s = Piece(white, 4, 4)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(black, 5, 4)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(white, 5, 5)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(black, 4, 5)
    piece_list.add(s)
    return piece_list


def flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player):
    for p in piece_list:
        if p.x == move[0] + (i + 1) * flip[0] and p.y == move[1] + (i + 1) * flip[1]:
            new_piece = Piece(player, p.x, p.y)
            piece_list.add(new_piece)
            piece_list.remove(p)
            return piece_list


def main():
    piece_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    piece_list = set_up_pieces(piece_list)
    player_to_move = white
    # this simulates a move
    move = [5, 3]
    new_piece = Piece(player_to_move, move[0], move[1])
    piece_list.add(new_piece)
    flip = [-1, 0, 2]
    for i in range(flip[2]):
        piece_list = flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player_to_move)


main()
```

NOTE: the flip variable contains the flip direction for x, y, and then the number of flips required. Knowledge of othello may be required to understand that explanation.

Comment: First off, Welcome to Stackoverflow! For questions, it is best practice to give the simplest example that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`piece_list` is becoming `None` because it is being set to the output of `flip_piece()`:

```
...
def flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player):
    for p in piece_list:
        if p.x == move[0] + (i + 1) * flip[0] and p.y == move[1] + (i + 1) * flip[1]:
            new_piece = Piece(player, p.x, p.y)
            piece_list.add(new_piece)
            piece_list.remove(p)
            return piece_list
...
def main():
    ...
    for i in range(flip[2]):
        piece_list = flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player_to_move)
    ...
```

The problem is `flip_piece()` returns the list `piece_list()` **if at least one item is modified**. This is because the return statement, is inside of the if statement, so a maximum of one piece is ever modified when flip_piece is called.

However, `piece_list` is not returned if no pieces are flipped. In python, if there is not a return statement, the function returns a `None` object. It is this object that is creating the error message.

By the rules of Othello (and some understanding of what your code does), I believe your function is supposed to look like this:

```
def flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player):
    for p in piece_list:
        if p.x == move[0] + (i + 1) * flip[0] and p.y == move[1] + (i + 1) * flip[1]:
            new_piece = Piece(player, p.x, p.y)
            piece_list.add(new_piece)
            piece_list.remove(p)
            return piece_list
    return piece_list
```

This will make it so there is always a return list, and fix the issue.

**However** pygame.sprite.Group() is a mutable object. This means that when you add or remove from `piece_list` in `flip_piece()`, the variable is already updated in `main()`. So you can simplify your code by just not returning anything.

Here is a complete version of what your code would look like.

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)


class Piece(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


def set_up_pieces(piece_list):
    s = Piece(white, 4, 4)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(black, 5, 4)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(white, 5, 5)
    piece_list.add(s)
    s = Piece(black, 4, 5)
    piece_list.add(s)
    return piece_list


def flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player):
    for p in piece_list:
        if p.x == move[0] + (i + 1) * flip[0] and p.y == move[1] + (i + 1) * flip[1]:
            new_piece = Piece(player, p.x, p.y)
            piece_list.add(new_piece)
            piece_list.remove(p)
            return

def main():
    piece_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    piece_list = set_up_pieces(piece_list)
    player_to_move = white
    # this simulates a move
    move = [5, 3]
    new_piece = Piece(player_to_move, move[0], move[1])
    piece_list.add(new_piece)
    flip = [-1, 0, 2]
    for i in range(flip[2]):
        flip_piece(piece_list, move, i, flip, player_to_move)


main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the idea is that it only flips one piece (in the actual code I have error checking to make sure that that always happens) as I have the for loop in the main to deal with the repeated flips in different locations. Also won't your code end up in an infinite loop within the flio_piece function as each item added will then be replaced as it goes through the loop because it meets the criteria?

Comment: I sincerely apologise - I tried it out and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect only modifying a single element.

Comment: As for an infinite loop, this does not repeat indefinitely as pygame.sprite.Group only iterates over the elements it had before a for loop started.